# ScheduledExecutorService and Shutdown Hook

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

When I use a `ScheduledExecutorService` (or ExecutorService) and submit a Runnable, my shutdown hook never gets called. Ex, this program hangs:

```
public class App {
  static ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

  static {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        exec.shutdownNow();
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
      }
    }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

Since the executor's thread is not a daemon, I would expect the shutdown hook to be called, but it's not. Any idea why?

Comment: Why do you think the shutdown hook would be invoked?

Comment: _I wouldn't expect the shutdown hook to be called, but it's not._ Isn't that what you expect?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I edited his question as I believe this was a typo.

Comment: _Since the executor's thread is not a daemon_ If it's not a daemon, it has to complete before the VM can exit.

Comment: You should explicitly call `shutdownNow()` somewhere, not through a hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event you absolutely need to shutdown the executor after the task has run you can implement something like this:

```
static {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Logger.getGlobal().info("destroying");
            exec.shutdownNow();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Future f = exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Logger.getGlobal().info("thread run");

        }
    }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    while (!f.isDone()) {
        Logger.getGlobal().info("waiting for task to finish");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the javadoc of [`Runtime#addShutdownHook(Thread)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-):

> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of
>   events:
>
> - **The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked**, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or
>     system shutdown.*****

As you said yourself, the threads in the `Executor` returned by `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` are not daemon threads. So they must exit before your shutdown hook can be invoked.

You're doing things backwards. You need to shutdown your `Executor` from some other part of your program's execution, not the shutdown hook. The shutdown hook will run after the `Executor` has terminated.

<sub>* Assuming you aren't trying to send a user interrupt to your `java` process.</sub>